# In a DAG, what is the name for a vertex with only one predecessor and one successor?

Tags: graphs, terminology, dag

In a directed acyclic graph (DAG), what is the name for a vertex with only one predecessor and one successor?

[image]

Comment: I don't think a common term for such a vertex exists. Why do you wonder?

Comment: @Arthelais because I use vertices of this type, and I don't want invented a name if this exists previously.

Comment: I also have not heard of a term for this, although it seems like it might deserve one.

Comment: It's part of a linear chain, but I don't know a specific name of *single* nodes in such a chain.

Comment: Naming them "two-chains" will totally make them easy to google in the future :P

Will Hunting's problem was to enumerate all unlabeled trees of a certain size that did not have these degree-two vertices. In that case, I believe that the problem was to find all "series-reduced" trees of a certain size, which seems to suggest that either a "series" or a chain might be a good terminology for this?